# Historic (lab) Page Speed Data via API

Tags: pagespeed

Is it possible to pull the page speed data (I require a performance score to visualise it as a graph in a report)  for the past period of time on a daily basis? As an output, I will need a table that would list the Page Speed Insight Metrics together with the past dates
Do you know, whether it is possible?

I tried pulling the data via an API provider and saving it to a BigQuery, however, when I try to display the data in a report (powerbi) I see only one date from the fetch, and I need multiple past dates to build a graph

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.